# Error: Some functions failed to load in Firebase Console functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Getting the error "Some functions failed to load" in Firebase Console functions (https://i.stack.imgur.com/30EwZ.png)

When click on Get 404 error link shows this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP4Md.png)

When click on Post 400 link shows this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRRh4.png)

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Im getting the same error..

Comment: I think there might be a widespread issue on the Firebase Function Console page. Until then use https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list

Comment: Did you able to find any solotion?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add .json for post the data to the data base Ex. Yourfirebaseurl/ListJobs.json like this

Comment: where could you please explain it more?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).